# Проверка на совпадения в нескольких таблицах (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Ребята, такой вопрос.

Есть несколько таблиц, например

```
table1
table2
table3
table4
...
```

В каждой таблице есть определенное поле(везде разное) которое содержит строку, скажем название.

Суть в том, чтобы пробегать по всем таблицам, заглядывать в поле каждой таблицы и искать совпадения и если хоть В ОДНОЙ есть уже такое же поле, то делать ему +1.
Т.е., скажем я добавляю название Новость - идет проверка по этим таблицам и если там есть хоть одно Новость или Новость-2 или Новость-3, то добавлять +1 к уже имеющимся.

Пример по одной таблице

```
$data = 'Новость';
$a = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(news_title) AS count FROM news WHERE news_title LIKE '".$data."%'");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);
$result = $r['count'] ? $data.'-'.($r['count']+1) : $data;
```

Вопрос в том, как это сделать по куче таблиц с разными полями в удобном варианте?

Comment: Почему много таблиц вместо одной? Не проще ли использовать одну таблицу, добавив в нее новое поле, по которому сможете классифицировать данные?

Comment: так изначально было сделано, просто не было необходимости проверять на уникальность. переделывать смысла нет уже.

Comment: А если этим табличкам UNION с нужным полем сделать (или во вьюху вынести) и по результату уже смотреть - чем не вариант?

Answer (score 1):

на вскидку сделать таблицу с метаданными

```
table_name field_name
Таблица1    поле1
Таблица2    поле2
Таблица3    поле3
```

вытаскивать из нее данные и динамически формировать SQL-запрос.
Можно еще поиграться со справочниками MySQL и попробовать оттуда вытащить информацию о таблицах и полях

Comment: Я вот подумал, что может сделать так
Если есть совпадение в таблицах, то собирать эти совпадения в массив и в нем уже делать сортировку и искать значение которое самое большое по счету?